# GUI restart vs. CLI reboot

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, reboot

I previously thought that clicking on the GUI restart button calls on /sbin/reboot the same way `sudo reboot` works. However, I now realize that CLI reboot requires sudo but GUI restart does not. Is there a difference between restarting in GUI as opposed to `sudo reboot`?

I understand that there is a GUI shell and a CLI shell both of which make calls to the kernel. Is it possible to track what executables are run for GUI tasks? In this case, is there a way to find out what executable is called when I click on the restart button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to track what executables are run for GUI tasks? In this case, is there a way to find out what executable is called when I click on the restart button?

There isn't any. Not all operations work by means of starting an executable. (And indeed, how would that executable *itself* perform the operation?) In the case of GNOME or KDE, the "Shutdown" button sends IPC messages to system services – this could be *reproduced* using a CLI tool, but does not use a CLI tool by itself.

To monitor D-Bus IPC calls use `busctl monitor` or `dbus-monitor` with the "--system" option, and to replicate the operations yourself through CLI, use `busctl call` or `gdbus call` (or the less convenient `dbus-send`). A graphical explorer named D-Feet is also available.

You can trace a program's kernel-level operations using 'strace' – this includes file access, IPC, networking, and so on. For example, `strace -f -e execve -p $PID` would show you what executables are being called by that particular process.

> I understand that there is a GUI shell and a CLI shell both of which make calls to the kernel.

Neither of them actually asks the kernel to restart – this is always a privileged operation because it wouldn't cleanly stop any programs or services; it would at best just flush unwritten files before "pulling the plug".

Instead, all shutdown or reboot requests are sent to the 'init' system (systemd in most cases, previously upstart or sysvinit). Traditionally, the `reboot` command sent a message through the /dev/initctl socket, although with systemd or upstart it uses D-Bus.

init only asks the kernel to restart as the very last step after all services have been shut down and filesystems unmounted.

> Is there a difference between restarting in GUI as opposed to sudo reboot?

The CLI command talks directly to 'init', which normally requires the caller to be root.

The GUI buttons instead send a message to the 'logind' service (or previously, to ConsoleKit) using D-Bus IPC, and it's that service which asks 'init' to perform a clean reboot.

The difference is that logind or CK itself allows the reboot request to come from any user as long as they have a local session active, i.e. they're the person currently using the keyboard and display. (The idea is that the local user could just press the physical power button anyway.)

The "systemd" init system actually comes with the `systemctl restart` command which allows unprivileged reboot the same way GUIs do it – by calling into logind. (For ConsoleKit this needs to be scripted using 'gdbus' etc.)

Note that although logind initiates the reboot in the same way that the 'reboot' command would – but again, it doesn't actually *run* the command; it directly uses the IPC system.

Comment: "The "systemd" init system actually comes with the systemctl restart" - I think you meant `systemctl reboot`. Also - "The CLI command talks directly to 'init', which normally requires the caller to be root." - at least on my system `/sbin/reboot` is really a symlink to `/bin/systemctl`, which leads me to think the two are equivalent. I can't be sure though, as I haven't seen `systemctl`'s implementation.